# GGPLOT grouped bar plot with facets: multiple aligned labels per bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet, grouped-table

(EDIT: The issues raised in this post are solved below)

I am trying to get my bar plot to look a certain way. I hope you can follow me without really explaining what the purpose of this plot is or the context of the data, so I'll dive right in.

I'm using this code

```
ggplot(ds, aes(x=fraction, y=AUC)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(demographics, c("adjusted", "not adjusted"))), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat="identity") + 
    facet_grid(~FN, switch="x") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=round(AUC, 2), fontface="bold", vjust=-0.4), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), size=2.75) +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="bottom", 
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
            panel.background=element_blank())
```

to produce the following plot

[image]

What I want to see, however, is

1. that the AUC-values on top of the bars are correctly aligned with every single bar (grouped by "demographics" [adjusted/not adjusted]) and not with the middle of the group "fraction" (serum/plasma) as it is right now
2. that the two bars in the last facet "FN=5" each have only half of their current width (to match the width of the other bars in facets "FN=1" to "FN=4"
3. that there is another label printed vertically within every bar. This label is stored in the character variable "features" contained in the data set "ds" used to print the plot

[image]

```
ds <- structure(list(ds = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
                            "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), FN = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
                            4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
                            2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                            5L), .Label = c("FN=1", "FN=2", "FN=3", "FN=4", "FN=5"), class = "factor"), 
            fraction = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                            1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("serum", 
                            "plasma"), class = "factor"), demographics = structure(c(1L, 
                            1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("not adjusted", "adjusted (age, sex, education, ethnicity, ApoE4)"
                    ), class = "factor"), AUC = c(0.741264171455195, 0.749961174095356, 
                    0.797639384997671, 0.763006678055599, 0.894704146606616, 
                    0.9038670601025, 0.90169280944246, 0.912564062742662, 0.912564062742662, 
                    0.672077922077922, 0.715367965367965, 0.746753246753247, 
                    0.791125541125541, 0.804112554112554, 0.827922077922078, 
                    0.829004329004329, 0.83982683982684, 0.83982683982684, 0.741264171455195, 
                    0.749961174095356, 0.797639384997671, 0.763006678055599, 
                    0.894704146606616, 0.9038670601025, 0.90169280944246, 0.912564062742662, 
                    0.912564062742662, 0.672077922077922, 0.715367965367965, 
                    0.746753246753247, 0.791125541125541, 0.804112554112554, 
                    0.827922077922078, 0.829004329004329, 0.83982683982684, 0.83982683982684
            ), features = c("p21", "p3 + p21", "p3 + p7 + p19", "p1 + p8 + p21 + p23", 
                    "p8", "p11 + p24", "p14 + p17 + p24", "p11 + p13 + p14 + p17", 
                    "p11 + p13 + p14 + p17", "p13", "p9 + p17", "p9 + p14 + p17", 
                    "p7 + p9 + p17 + p19", "p20", "p9 + p19", "p9 + p17 + p19", 
                    "p4 + p8 + p9 + p17", "p4 + p8 + p9 + p17", "p21", "p3 + p21", 
                    "p3 + p7 + p19", "p1 + p8 + p21 + p23", "p8", "p11 + p24", 
                    "p14 + p17 + p24", "p11 + p13 + p14 + p17", "p11 + p13 + p14 + p17", 
                    "p13", "p9 + p17", "p9 + p14 + p17", "p7 + p9 + p17 + p19", 
                    "p20", "p9 + p19", "p9 + p17 + p19", "p4 + p8 + p9 + p17", 
                    "p4 + p8 + p9 + p17")), .Names = c("ds", "FN", "fraction", 
            "demographics", "AUC", "features"), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: Eventually, using the help in the comments section, I used this code

```
            ggplot(ds, aes(x=fraction, y=AUC, fill=factor(demographics, c("adjusted (age, sex, education, ethnicity, ApoE4)", "not adjusted")))) + 
                geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat="identity") + 
                facet_grid(~FN) + 
                geom_text(aes(label=round(AUC, 2), fontface="bold", vjust=1), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), size=2.75) + 
                geom_text(aes(y=0.3, label=features, fontface="bold"), color="white", position=position_dodge(width=0.9), angle=90, size=3) + 
                theme_bw() +
                theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="bottom", 
                        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                        axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold"), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
                        panel.background=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank())
```

to produce the results I initially wanted (I changed my mind on halving the width of the columns in facet "FN=5" though), looking like this

[image]

To increase readability, I decided to flip the plot using this code

```
            ggplot(ds, aes(x=fraction, y=AUC, fill=factor(demographics, c("not adjusted", "adjusted (age, sex, education, ethnicity, ApoE4)")))) + 
                geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat="identity") + 
                facet_grid(FN~.) + 
                geom_text(aes(y=AUC, label=round(AUC, 2), fontface="bold"), position=position_dodge(width=0.9),  hjust=1.15, size=3.25) + 
                geom_text(aes(y=0.4, label=features, fontface="bold"), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), color="white", size=3) + 
                theme_bw() +
                theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="bottom", 
                        axis.title.x=element_text(face="bold"), axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
                        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
                        panel.background=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.grid.major=element_blank(),   
                        strip.text.y = element_text(angle=0)) + coord_flip()
```

which results in a horizontal bar plot now looking like this (colors and order of legend keys are not quite right yet)

[image]

Comment: Pls make you question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Use `dput(d)` instead of an image of the data

Comment: Get the dev version of ggplot, then use `position_dodge(preserve = "single")` for both geoms. You also need to set the `group` for `geom_text` appropriately to allow for dodging. This is probably automatic is you move the fill aesthetic to `ggplot` instead of `geom_bar`. Images of data are not useful. Please ask one question per question.

Comment: @GGamba Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the info.

Comment: @Axeman Thanks for your tips. I fixed the problem with the labels above the bars not aligning with the middle of the respective bar by moving `fill=factor(demographics, c("adjusted", "not adjusted"))` to `ggplot` instead of `geom_bar` - just as you advised me to do.